# How do I show up a YouTube preview pic?

Tags: joomla-3.6

How do I show up a YouTube preview picture?

[Get into My site](https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="video.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="video">
        <a class="video__link" href="http://youtu.be/IDSJ0iMLq_U">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp" type="image/webp">
                <img class="video__media" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="7 steps in moving a piano from Piano movers Toronto #1.">
            </picture>
        </a>
        <button class="video__button" aria-label="Start">
            <svg width="68" height="48" viewBox="0 0 68 48"><path class="video__button-shape" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"></path><path class="video__button-icon" d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34"></path></svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script src="video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant show up preview. what am I doing wrong?
[image]

```
 <div><div class="video video--enabled"> <a class="video__link"> <picture> <source srcset="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp" type="image/webp"> <img class="video__media" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="7 steps in moving a piano from Piano movers Toronto #1."> </picture> </a> <button class="video__button" aria-label="Start the video"> <svg width="68" height="48" viewBox="0 0 68 48"><path class="video__button-shape" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"></path><path class="video__button-icon" d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34"></path></svg> </button> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your page your website is loaded via https, but the image link is provided without http.

what does your console show?
simply by copy your HTML i cannot see an error, in the code itself.

Comment: I add below the pic code from console. Do you wanna see it?

Comment: I was wrong before. Console show it : `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: should I use https instead of http?

Comment: thank you Sir. I help Me solved it

Comment: Point of order.  An answer must not be posted to ask for question clarification -- use a comment under the question to ask for details/clarity.  If new questions details are to be added to this page, they must be edited into the question.  I am (personally) failing to see how this answer "solves" the question.

Comment: got it Sir. I got message from console that I use http instead of https. Mixed content the page. `'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp'` there is http if you got the same issue you have to replace `http` on `https`